# How to get the slope from an elevation raster in QGIS?

Tags: raster, qgis-3, slope, distribution, habitat-modeling

I need to extract the slope from an elevation raster in order to do a species distribution model.
It should be quite straightforward, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I am running QGIS 3.10 on a Windows10.
I have tried using the QGIS and GDAL functions for "slope". Both give similar results, as shown in the pictures below. The first is of the original topo file, and the second is the output where the entire area is fuzzy and uniform. There isn't even a difference between the sea and the land, and I can confirm, this area is NOT flat! I have tried using different topo files, but it has given me similar results where everything is uniform.

[image: pic 1: original topo file]

[image: pic 2: QGIS slope output]

Here is the other raster file I have been using, with its output as well.
I have tried to change the symbology, but it remains the same; that isn't the problem...
[image: 2nd topo file]
[image]

I have also tried using the GRASS7 function for the "r.slope.aspect" but it gives me an error message (shown below) that I have not been able to figure out... However, even if I get the GRASS7 modules working, I don't think this will solve my problem, as the same thing is happening with both the QGIS and GDAL functions.
[image: GRASS7 error message]

I am quite new to GIS and am struggling through every hurdle.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you are not using a digital elevation model (DEM) data. It is just an image (scanned image) from layout or something and not a real elevation data. You need to use elevation data such as SRTM data or any other data that stores elevation. Working with scanned figures will not produce any meaningful results.

Comment: Yeah, this is most likely a hillshade image, including rivers and highways.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the images you provided, and the previous answer from ahmadhanb, you are going to need actual elevation data, not just scanned images.

The BC Government provides a free DEM [elevation data](https://www2.gov.bc.ca/gov/content/data/geographic-data-services/topographic-data/elevation/digital-elevation-model) through its
website.

Another option is the [30 meter SRTM tile data](https://dwtkns.com/srtm30m/) which is free and easily downloadable.

You may need to mosaic the elevation data together prior to running the slope calculation if the area you are looking at is larger than a single tile and it is necessary to download more than one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'm still quite stumped though as the files I used (and posted above) are from the very same BC gov database that you provided. Therefore, this should be proper DEM data right? I went though and re-downloaded the file through the link above, but it's still giving me the same result. Any more ideas on what the problem could be? I just need a single tile: 92G51, but I need the best resolution possible, so the 30 meter SRTM data won't do...

Comment: Do you mean 92G15? Can't find a 92G51, assuming you are searching the CDED data. I downloaded 92G15 west from https://pub.data.gov.bc.ca/datasets/175624/ and it provided a proper DEM.

Comment: Thanks Adam! I don't know how I came across the first file; the directory looks exactly like the one you sent me but the tile numbers are different for the same location!

Comment: So after looking through all of them, the correct tile number is 92G12w. However, I still can't seem to extract the slope. It comes out uniform, the sea being = to 0 and everything else = 90. This is especially weird since the tool for aspect is working just fine. Any thoughts? Thank you so much!

Comment: I do not have QGIS as work, but it sounds like an awfully familiar problem. Does it change if you play around with the options in the Style tab? Change the render type, contrast etc.